# Get a value of a row in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table contains the following Data

```
id     student      class      
1      English       3-B      
2      null          null   
3      null          null   
4      Jack          OuMe 
5      Richard       DSA      
6      Jhon          Ross   
7      French        5-B       
8      null         null      
9      null         null      
10     Cena         ADI        
11     Mike         Rock          
12     Philip       DSK
```

I need a select query to get the resultant as below:

```
  id       student       class    classSTUD  
    1      English       3-B       3-B
    2      null          null      3-B
    3      null          null      3-B
    4      Jack          OuMe      3-B
    5      Richard       DSA       3-B
    6      Jhon          Ross      3-B
    7      French        5-B       5-B
    8      null         null       5-B
    9      null         null       5-B
    10     Cena         ADI        5-B
    11     Mike         Rock       5-B   
    12     Philip       DSK        5-B
```

i tried the query as bellow but i didn't get the right result

```
SELECT ID, STUDENT, CLASS,
NVL (CLASS, LAG(CLASS IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) CLASSSTUD
FROM MYTABLE 
ORDER BY ID;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem I improved the response answered by Gordon Linoff

```
SELECT ID, STUDENT, CLASS,
     NVL(CASE WHEN CLASS LIKE '%-%' THEN CLASS END, LAG(CASE WHEN CLASS LIKE '%-%' THEN CLASS END) IGNORE NULLS OVER
           (ORDER BY ID)) as CLASSSTUD
FROM MYTABLE 
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a serious flaw in your database design. You need two tables to make this work properly. You are mixing two different categories of data in the same column which is why you are having an issue. You have classes and students in the same column.

Create a separate table for classes and one for students.

I have no idea why you have a table that contains only null values.

Classes table:

```
id    class    classcode
1     English  3-B
2     French   5-B
```

Students table:

```
id    student  classid
1     Jack     1
2     Richard  1
3     Jhon     1
4     Cena     2
5     Mike     2
6     Philip   2
```

If, as I suspect is the case what I presume are your class codes are unique, then they are a natural key anyway, so you could do it like this:

Classes table:

```
classcode    class
3-B          English
5-B          French
```

Students table:

```
id    student    classcode
1     Jack       3-B
2     Richard    3-B
3     Jhon       3-B
4     Cena       5-B
5     Mike       5-B
6     Philip     5-B
```

I have left the id field in the Students table because it is probable that you will have two Jacks/Richards/Jhons/whatevers at some point, so having a unique id makes sense.

If you are stuck with the data as shown I think you are in real trouble.

Comment: this is a xml file and i loaded it in a table using `ETL`(Oracle Data integrator) and i need to do a transformation but i need a query statement

Comment: This suggests to me that perhaps a better question to ask would have been how to make ODI import an XML file into a given (better) data structure. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the product, and consequently can't answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what your data structure really represents, but it seems like you need something like this:

```
SELECT ID, STUDENT, CLASS,
       LAG((CASE WHEN CLASS LIKE '%-%' THEN CLASS END) IGNORE NULLS) OVER
           (ORDER BY ID) as CLASSSTUD
FROM MYTABLE 
ORDER BY ID;
```